# Shopware : How to get customFields for products in the Order Object

Tags: php, symfony, data-access-layer, shopware, shopware6

I am currently trying to get a custom field '*emakers_custom_field_warehouse_name*' in the products when an order is made with the code below.

Here's my search Request :

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $orderId));
$criteria->addAssociations([
     'deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.salutation',
     'deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country',
     'orderCustomer.customer.group',
     'lineItems.product.translations',
]);
$orderObject = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria), Context::createDefaultContext())->first();
```

Here's what I get when I serialize $orderObject->getLineItems->first()->getProduct() :
https://gist.github.com/Youmar0504/8b53632fbc1b43c11769711519a74a17

What I already tried and gave me empty result :

```
$orderObject->getLineItems->first()->getProduct()->getCustomFields()
```

TBH, I don't know what to try else. It looks like (if you search on the customField's name in the gist) that it's in the product Translation Entity. But if I do $orderObject->getLineItems->first()->getProduct()->getProductTranslations(), I receive an error saying "**Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProductTranslations" of class "Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEntity**"

Anything else I can try to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out that this was language dependant. Just replaced in the ***criteria*** :
**'lineItems.product.translations'** by **'lineItems.product.default'** and I am now easily getting the customFields by doing :

```
$orderObject->getLineItems->first()->getProduct()->getCustomFields()
```